# combine two php array for json encode

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

Presently m working with CakePhp..i got some problem with combining two array and prepare for a json encoded array.. i used array_merge() property but its not working.. how can i encoded both of these two array..

M doing like this :

```
return json_encode(array_merge ($product_list,$price_list));
```

i have two php array as follows :

array 1:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PriceList] => Array
                (
                    [price_id] => 2
                    [price_name] => abc
                    [date_time] => 2015-07-06 16:22:56
                    [dealer_type] => Dealer
                    [purpose] => dealer
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PriceList] => Array
                (
                    [price_id] => 3
                    [price_name] => xyz
                    [date_time] => 2015-07-06 16:22:56
                    [dealer_type] => Dealer
                    [purpose] => dealer
                    [status] => ACTIVE
                )

        )

)
```

array 2:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_id] => 3
                    [brand_id] => 1
                    [p_code] => PP12567
                    [name] => akai
                    [model_no] => 
                    [specification] => color tv
                    [color] => 
                    [quality] => 
                    [size] => 
                    [p_unavail] => 1
                    [demo_avail] => 0
                    [brochure] => 
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductPrice] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 154
                    [p_code] => PP12567
                    [price_id] => 1
                    [quantity] => 233
                    [purchase_price] => 344.00
                    [selling_price] => 44.00
                    [discount_price] => 33.00
                    [tax] => 5.00
                    [datetime] => 2015-07-23 15:47:11
                )

            [ProductSubCategory] => Array
                (
                    [subcat_id] => 3
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_name] => samsung
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductCategory] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Electronics
                    [cat_type] => Product 
                    [status] => active
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_id] => 4
                    [brand_id] => 1
                    [p_code] => PBC-676767
                    [name] => music
                    [model_no] => 33
                    [specification] => 
                    [color] => 
                    [quality] => 
                    [size] => 
                    [p_unavail] => 0
                    [demo_avail] => 0
                    [brochure] => 
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductPrice] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 156
                    [p_code] => PBC-676767
                    [price_id] => 1
                    [quantity] => 767
                    [purchase_price] => 54.00
                    [selling_price] => 55.00
                    [discount_price] => 22.00
                    [tax] => 3.00
                    [datetime] => 2015-07-23 15:47:11
                )

            [ProductSubCategory] => Array
                (
                    [subcat_id] => 4
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [subcat_name] => sony
                    [status] => active
                )

            [ProductCategory] => Array
                (
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [cat_name] => Electronics
                    [cat_type] => Product 
                    [status] => active
                )

        )
)
```

how to combine these two array into one and encoded into a json array..

Comment: Hi, you can use php array_merge function.

Comment: What you expect is not obvious. Also `i used array_merge() property but its not working` - not working _in what way_? Please explain what you're expecting and what is actually happening _with what code_.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `array_merge` but not directly on `array1` and `array2`:

```
$toEncodeArray = [array_merge ($array1[0], $array2[0])] ;
```

If you only want the associative array (without the wrapping array), simply do:

```
$toEncodeArray = array_merge ($array1[0], $array2[0]) ;
```

Comment: Could just as easily do `$stuff[0] = $one[0] + $two[0]; // Use $stuff`, or even `$two[0]['PriceList'] = $one[0]['PriceList']; // Use $two` _IF_ that's what the question actually means.